# Лишние числа при отправке/получении запроса

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image: Numbers]

Здравствуйте. Не пойму откуда и кто или "что" дописывает лишние цифры к номеру. Какой бы он ни был: состоял из одной или нескольких цифр - именно эти числа (1116) и дописываются. В чем может быть дело? (редакторами ничего не прикрыл)
JS писал через class Cart {} (из за этого и this в коде увидите)

Comment: Нашел проблему. Это из за фильтра $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"phone", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
Когда убрал FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT то данные поступают так как и ввели. Откуда фильтр берет эти числа и сам дописывает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, оформите исходный код текстом.

Comment: Ну логично же, что 5 групп цифр через пробел - это не int...

Comment: Все еще не понимаю, в чем проблема. 5 груп цифр через пробел не int но разве filter-input-sanitize-number не "удаляет эти пробелы и прочие символы кроме плюса и минуа"?
Я могу код полностью отправить но в этом нет смысла так как там его  на 160 строк. На фото как раз размещена та часть кода, которая имеет участь в происходящем.